# An API for convert a function to callback function in MASM

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I want an API to convert all of the functions in `MASM` code to callback function . if we use API functions in code we can use `GetProcAddresses` API , for callback them in code but if we have functions that we declare them ( not API) how we can callback them with API?

Answer (score 0):

`GetProcAddress` deals with exported functions from a DLL, so you have to export them from your module and create a DLL out of it. It is a bit unclear what exactly you want to do. If you are thinking of exporting functions from a a regular exe file, then this is not possible.

For a more detailed information on how to create a DLL with MASM you can read [this link](http://www.website.masmforum.com/tutorials/dlltute/masmdll.htm).

Comment: the prograqm example is too long to show here , say an email to send you program

Comment: Why should I give you my email? I'm not going to write this for you. Read the link and apply the changes you need to export the functions.

Comment: no , I read link but it is not my goal!
I have a program that have several native functions , I don't want to export them in Dll , I want to use an API to change them to callback mode , I want to show the program , but it is too long to show here!
I wanted to send program to your mail , so need your mail!

Comment: You could write a callback function code example in C, then have the compiler produce assembly code, so that you could see what is needed for an assembler version of the same type of function.

Comment: @user3291634: A callback for _what_? The Win32 API? In that case you have to make your functions follow the `stdcall` calling convention. This is something you do in the source code, not at runtime.

Comment: @Michael, but adding the CALLBACK doesn't allow you to query the address with GetProcAdress, or am I wrong on this? Not 100% sure, because in the API you need a module handle, which could also be an executable.

Comment: @Devolus: Right. It was a bit unclear to me exactly what the OP wants to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can export functions from an exe!  There are a few ways to do it.

Use the `/EXPORT` parameter for `link`

> link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /EXPORT:Proc_To_Export file.obj

This can get messy if you want to export many functions, in that case, just create a `def` file as you would for a DLL.

```
EXPORTS Func1_Name
Func2_Name
Func3_Name
etc...
```

> link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /DEF:DEF_name program_name.obj

Another way is just to tell MASM that your proc is to be exported with `export`

```
include masm32rt.inc

.code
start:    

AddTwo PROC EXPORT FirstNum:DWORD, SecondNum:DWORD    
    mov     eax, FirstNum
    add     eax, SecondNum
    ret
AddTwo ENDP

end start
```

Assemble and link that then, assemble and link the following as a console app:

```
include masm32rt.inc
includelib Add2_Exported.lib
AddTwo PROTO FirstNum:DWORD,SecondNum:DWORD

.code
start:
    invoke  AddTwo, 200, 3456

    print str$(eax), 13, 10
    inkey
    invoke  ExitProcess, 0
end start
```

In this example, I put the `add2_exported.exe`, and the corresponding lib file in the same directory as the sample console app.

[image]

As you can see, the function **is** exported and the result of the console app calling that exported function.

You can also use `LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddress`:

```
include masm32rt.inc

.data
szAppName   db  "add2_exported.exe", 0
szFunction db  "_AddTwo@8", 0

.code
start:
    invoke  LoadLibrary, offset szAppName
    mov     esi, eax

    invoke  GetProcAddress, eax, 1 ; use ordinal 
    push    3456
    push    200
    call    eax
    print str$(eax), 13, 10

    invoke  GetProcAddress, esi, offset szFunction ; use function name
    push    3456
    push    500
    call    eax
    print str$(eax), 13, 10

    invoke  FreeLibrary, esi   

    inkey
    invoke  ExitProcess, 0
end start
```